# I have four class. One of them is broadcast receiver; other two are normal class extending activity.

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have four class. One of them is broadcast receiver; other three are normal class extending activity. 
I am sending information from one of these activities to broadcast receiver. 
Now I want to know if there is way, based on value received in broadcast receiver to run any of remaining two activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use intent component,like below

```
public class YourbroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    //start activity
    Intent myi=new Intent(ctx,YourAnotherActivity.class);
    ctx.startActivity(myi);
}
```

Comment: What if i want to set the intent from the value received in this class?
Thanks

Comment: what's differents of the two class? they both response the brocast receiver?

Comment: @Roshan : its you business logic that you can write in onReceive() method.